# PHP install sqlite3 extension

Tags: php, centos, sqlite, extension

We are using PHP 5.3.6 here, but we used the --without-sqlite3 command when compiling PHP. (It stands in the 'Configure Command' column). But, it is very risky to recompile PHP on that server; there are many visitors. How can we install/use sqlite3?

Regards,
Kevin

[EDIT]

**yum repolist gives:**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
repo id                        repo name                                  status
base                           CentOS-5 - Base                            3,566
extras                         CentOS-5 - Extras                            237
updates                        CentOS-5 - Updates                           376
repolist: 4,179
```

**rpm -qa | grep php gives:**

```
php-pdo-5.3.6-1.w5
php-mysql-5.3.6-1.w5
psa-php5-configurator-1.5.3-cos5.build95101022.10
php-mbstring-5.3.6-1.w5
php-imap-5.3.6-1.w5
php-cli-5.3.6-1.w5
php-gd-5.3.6-1.w5
php-5.3.6-1.w5
php-common-5.3.6-1.w5
php-xml-5.3.6-1.w5
```

**php -i | grep sqlite gives:**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-mime-magic' '--without-sqlite' '--without-sqlite3' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-readline' '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr' '--with-mssql=shared,/usr' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr'
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in Unknown on line 0
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
pdo_sqlite
PWD => /root/sqlite
_SERVER["PWD"] => /root/sqlite
_ENV["PWD"] => /root/sqlite
```

Comment: Are you running CentOS? And PHP is installed with yum, not compiled from source?

Comment: I'm not sure wether PHP was installed through yum (I thought so). And yes, it's on CentOS.

Comment: Edit your original post and append the output of `yum repolist` and `rpm -qa | grep php`?

Comment: It's added to the post ;)

Comment: `php -i | grep sqlite`?

Comment: Also added that one ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install php without it and then install the package: **php5-sqlite3**
then restart apache to make it work.

Comment: It then says: "No package php5-sqlite3 available." (when using yum install php5-sqlite3)

Comment: to get verify that if it is present in Yum repor, run "yum search sqlite | grep php", it will give you exact package name. install that php sqlite package.

Comment: :(, it gives: php-pear-Log.noarch : Abstracted logging facility for PHP

Comment: Add new reposirtory "EPEL" to yum by "wget http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
" and then install this rpm through "rpm ivh epel*"... considering that you are using RHEL 5 or CentOS 5. then run the yum search command i gave to you.

Comment: That url doesn't exists :(..

Comment: Kevin: sorry for that. please use this command to install epel repo: "rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm" i have verified, this url works fine.

Comment: @Frank: your second URL doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

> but we used the --without-sqlite3 command when compiling PHP. (It
>   stands in the 'Configure Command' column)

No. You didn't specify. It's the default option when installing binary package.

> But, it is very risky to recompile PHP on that server; there are many
>   visitors.

`--without-xx` from the **Configure Command** column in the `phpinfo()` page doesn't mean you have to recompile PHP to enable. For example, you can see `--without-mysql` option but you still can install `php-mysql` to enable it:

```
mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 5.5.15
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

Since you installed `php-pdo` package:

```
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.3.6
```

The `sqlite3` extension is already enabled, but in the different name [`pdo_sqlite`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php). Just use it to access to the SQLite 3 database.